# How to remove Microsoft Defender from macOS Network > Filters & Proxies

Tags: network, microsoft

I have  already uninstalled Microsoft Defender following Microsoft [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/mac-resources?view=o365-worldwide#uninstalling):

> Interactive uninstallation
>
> Open Finder > Applications. Right click on Microsoft Defender for Endpoint > Move to Trash.

Defender is not in my Applications folder anymore.

However, **System Settings** > **Network** > **Filters** > **Filters & Proxies** still show Microsoft Defender, and it is enabled but with a yellow dot.

[image]

This filter does not have enabled the option to disable.

Any suggestion how to get rid of this filter?

**Update:** after restarting the machine, the icon is gone, but filter/proxy still shows up:

[image]

Comment: Did you try the command line solution? Who installed this in the first place, you or a company/organisation? It seems an unlikely app to be self-installed.

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried, but the `/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Defender` does not exist

Comment: You didn't answer the second part, which is important - is this a managed machine, or your own personal? I'm really wondering how a corporate endpoint security got onto a personal Mac.

Comment: @Tetsujin, sorry, this is my personal computer, but I used it for work at some point, so it was managed by my employer

Comment: Check if there's an MDM. Simply go to “System Preferences”. If you don’t see a section as “Profiles” or “Profiles & Device Management”, then you don’t have any MDM on your Mac. On the other hand, click on “Profiles” or “Profiles & Device Management”. When it’s open, if you don’t see any profiles listed, then it means you don’t have any MDM profiles or it has been removed. Otherwise, you may have an MDM on your Mac. Also look in Activity monitor to see if a process called 'mdmclient' running.

Comment: @Tetsujin No MDM installed. This looks like a setting that was not cleaned up.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, sorry. See if you can find it with [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) (freeware) & delete it.

Answer (score 2):

As [Techyy25](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/495301/techyy25) mentioned, you can control this setting by modifying the `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.plist` file. However, on my machine which is managed I had to do more than just `sudo` to remove it. In recovery mode, I logged in as an admin and mounted the local /Users directory by running

```
diskutil apfs unlock "Macintosh HD - Data"
```

from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/427964/327645), then removed the files by backing them up into a different directory like so

```
mkdir /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.bak
mv /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.* /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.bak
```

Answer (score 1):

Made an account just to answer your question.

After a while of trying I managed to figure it out.

You need to remove the file: `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.plist`

You can do this from the terminal with:

`sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.plist`